# How can i pass parameters to schedule

Tags: python

How can I pass parameters to [scheduler](https://python-scheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/examples/quick_start.html)
Trying to use schedule with multiple parameters

cant figure it out

```
import time
import datetime as dt
from scheduler import Scheduler

schedule = Scheduler()

ItemName = "Crown"

Price = 5000

def SellItem(ItemName, Price):
    print(f"Item Name = {ItemName}\n"
          f"Item Price = {Price}")

SellItem(ItemName, Price + 50000)

schedule.once(dt.timedelta(seconds=10), SellItem(ItemName, Price + 50000))
#Runs both instantly like normal and 10 seconds later Gives me a TypeError NoneType object is not callable


while True:
    schedule.exec_jobs()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: The problem here isn't trying to "pass arguments to schedule"; it's trying to *bind* arguments to *the callback* that is passed. That, in turn, has nothing to do with the `schedule` module and is a matter of fundamental Python technique. Please see the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When scheduling a job, the scheduler expects a `Callable` as the `handle` parameter (the job you want executed) (see [the documentation](https://python-scheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/scheduler.threading.scheduler.Scheduler.html#scheduler.threading.scheduler.Scheduler.once)), however what `SellItem(ItemName, Price + 50000)` does is to **actually call the function**, and the argument passed to `Scheduler.once` is the what the function `SellItem` returns, which is nothing: `None`.
Hence, when trying to execute the job, you get the error you mention.

The code you've written is equivalent to

```py
result = SellItem(ItemName, Price + 50000)
schedule.once(dt.timedelta(seconds=10), result)
```

If you want the scheduler to run your function, you need to give it your function as an argument:
`schedule.once(dt.timedelta(seconds=10), SellItem)`.
Then, in order to provide arguments to the function `SellItem` when it is called, you can use the parameter `args` from the `Scheduler.once` function, as mentioned in [the documentation, here](https://python-scheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/examples/parameters.html)
So, with your code that would be:

```py
import time
import datetime as dt
from scheduler import Scheduler

schedule = Scheduler()

ItemName = "Crown"

Price = 5000

def SellItem(ItemName, Price):
    print(f"Item Name = {ItemName}\n"
          f"Item Price = {Price}")

schedule.once(dt.timedelta(seconds=10), SellItem, args=(ItemName, Price + 50000))


while True:
    schedule.exec_jobs()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Also, as a side note, you should try to follow PEP8 [recommendations regarding naming conventions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) for your variables and functions